# How to get a single result from mysql_multi_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli-multi-query

I have a procedural php script which employs a mysqli_multi_query statement into which I must now add a `SELECT` statement. After many attempts, I have to admit that this appears to be a bit outside my ken. I need some help with the grammar… or perhaps the procedure:

The code has `SELECT`ed nothing to this point, and therefore has never needed its results to be queried. **How would I retrieve a single result?**

Here is my script. I have omitted the details of the other queries.

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 ...;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @varX;
INSERT INTO table2 ...;
INSERT INTO table3 ...;
INSERT INTO table4 ...;
DELETE FROM table0;
SELECT `id` FROM subscribers WHERE `column` = @varX;
```

I want that last statement's `id` from `SELECT id FROM patronsSubscr WHERE column = @varX;`

They are run from php using this function:

```php
$result = mysqli_multi_query($connection,$sql)
    or die("Error.");
```

I have been trying to use variations of this, with no luck:

```
while($resultNexts = mysqli_next_result($result)){
    // output
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: by omitting the details of the queries you make it harder to answer but one method you could possibly employ would be to use a `stored procedure` - if the queries are run frequently with no deviation but alternative parameters that is. Create a SP on the db that does all the tasks and then as the final query does the select

Comment: I try to figure out what you mean by retrieve single result . Php will get confused if all queries are in one jar . If you want to retrieve just select statement then run it as single query.in such case I would use loop on all the queries and it will be much easy than the above method.

Comment: My general recommendation about `mysqli_multi_query` is DON'T USE IT. It just makes things more complicated, and provides little benefit.

Comment: @Barmar I've got that feeling already. Looking at that duplicate, I think it's pretty dirty. But I think that it will do the work until I get time to rebuild the whole script. Thanks, everyone.